# Logging with log4net in SharePoint timerjob

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, custom-timer-job

I am relatively new to SharePoint development and have been using log4net for logging inside my custom SharePoint projects.

I recently created my first timerjob and saw that log4net does not behave as expected when I debug the timerjob i.e. my logs dont show anything.

Anyone facing the same issue/anyone logging inside a timerjob?

Comment: I can't understand why SO put this Q on hold..What do you want people to ask then ? Some oversmart people here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logging implementation in the Patterns and Practices guidance for SharePoint 2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798395.aspx

It should work fine in an on-premises SP2013 farm.